# Where do closed notes in OS X Notes app go?

Tags: macos, notes.app

When you close a note in the OS X 10.9 Notes app it leaves no trace, there's no warning and no revert. It's just appears to be gone. Very unMac like to me. It's in user interface design 101 that if there's a risk of data loss, the application should inform the user of this is what will happen.

Where do the notes go in OS X if the default is "on this Mac"? What if the default account is an IMAP account? Can you get it back from the place it's connected to?

Comment: Could be better phrased as "where do the autosaved notes go". This "unMac" behavior is an extension of the autosaving features that Apple introduced, IIRC, in Lion.

Comment: That doesn't explain this as Apple connects auto-save to versions. In Notes there are no save, no version, no anything to clue you in on how it's supposed to work. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202255

Comment: Thanks for your reflection which put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this seem to be down to my unfamiliarity with the Notes app. As in "Mail" there is a browser overview under Window > Notes (Cmd-0) (in my language anyway) and any closed notes can be found there. 
Despite a long long use of OS X apps this didn't feel like a natural place to look, but it's logical considering other Apple apps. I think possibly "Note browser" would have said more about the function of this menu option. I must have understood this as a reference to the app itself.